# SWTBot Could not find node with text: Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, junit, eclipse-plugin, swtbot

I am using the SWTBot recorder to test a very simple feature. I just want to create a `Dynamic Web Project` and then delete it. But it won't even create the project. Why is it blowing up here?

Here is the code that the recorder generated:

```
@RunWith(SWTBotJunit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestSwtBot {

private static SWTWorkbenchBot bot = new SWTWorkbenchBot();

@Test
public void test() {        
     bot.menu("File").menu("New").menu("Other...").click();
     bot.tree().getTreeItem("Web").getNode("Dynamic Web Project").select();
     bot.textWithLabel("Project na&me:").setText("TestDynamicProject");
     bot.button("Next >").click();
     bot.button("Next >").click();
     bot.checkBox("Generate web.xml deployment descriptor").click();
     bot.button("Finish").click();
     bot.button("No").click();
     bot.checkBox("Delete project contents on disk (cannot be undone)").click();
     bot.button("OK").click();
}
```

So it is blowing up on this line:

```
bot.tree().getTreeItem("Web").getNode("Dynamic Web Project").select();
```

And here is the stacktrace:

```
org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.exceptions.WidgetNotFoundException: Could not find node with text: Dynamic Web Project
at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.SWTBotTreeItem.getNodes(SWTBotTreeItem.java:338)
at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.SWTBotTreeItem.getNode(SWTBotTreeItem.java:312)
at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.SWTBotTreeItem.getNode(SWTBotTreeItem.java:350)
at com.homedepot.is.dt.eclipse.swtbot.TestSwtBot.test(TestSwtBot.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.junit.SWTBotJunit4ClassRunner.run(SWTBotJunit4ClassRunner.java:54)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.core.RemotePluginTestRunner.main(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:64)
at org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.core.UITestApplication.runTests(UITestApplication.java:117)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Testable$1.run(E4Testable.java:73)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand the "Web" tree item first.

```
bot.tree().getTreeItem("Web").expand();
bot.tree().getTreeItem("Web").getNode("Dynamic Web Project").select();
```

Answer (score 1):

did you use Eclipse Spy to see if your calling the correct tree?, I mean, in this part of your code: `bot.tree()` you can call differents trees by their index, for example `bot.tree(0)` or `bot.tree(1)` maybe is looking for your node in another tree.

For more information about Eclipse spy, please see here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/FAQ#Can_I_get_more_details_on_a_particular_widget.3F

Comment: I tried `bot.tree(0)` and I received the same exception as above. When I did `bot.tree(1)` I received an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Is not about try with differents index. Please use the Eclipse Spy plugin to see more information about the tree where your node is located.

Comment: Okay gotcha! Looking into it!